# PHP code not identifying AM and PM in Datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have database with columns "event_start" in which date and time gets inserted in  "Y-m-d H:i:s a" format and "display_time" in which data get inserted as "Y-m-d H:i:s a" +45 minutes format during creating event. These columns types are varchar(255)

On my page I am displaying data from this database with display time in ascending pattern. But If dates are same in two rows, it is not showing am and then pm.

code used is as follows :

```
<?
$current_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s a");

$data=mysql_query("select * from  table where display_time >'".$current_date."' order by event_start asc"); 
?>
```

Now e.g. if two events are there.

event1 = event_start is 2014-07-15 08:00:00 am, so display_time gets inserted is 2014-07-15 08:45:00 am

event2 = event_start is 2014-07-15 16:00:00 pm, so display_time gets inserted is 2014-07-15 16:45:00 pm

In this case, event1 should be displayed above event2, But it is not getting in this manner.
It is showing event2 and then event1

Comment: What is the type of this "display_time" column.

Comment: varchar (255). already mentioned in first paragraph

Comment: sorry all members. Above Problem is related to jQuery datetimepicker addon. When I am adding date and time for event_start, it is inserting time as 03:00 pm for 15:00, And for 08:00 am for 08:00, so php coding is just checking 03:00 verses 08:00, so event2 (with 03:00 pm) gets above and then event2 (with 08:00 AM). But Now I made changes in Jquery. Now it is inserting 15:00 Instead of 03:00 PM...Now It Is Working....Thanx for bearing pains for my problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any use of am or pm in this. As the current date is in the 24 hour time format remove the additional am/pm
`$current_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`
Just use this one.

Comment: ok. i tried removing am and pm from database too....but till it showing event2 (with display_time 16:00) above and then event1 (with display_time  08:00)

Comment: @darshan try to change the display_time col to datetime! that is the right way to store time

Comment: sorry respected member. Above Problem was related to jQuery datetimepicker addon. When I am adding date and time for event_start, it is inserting time as 03:00 pm for 15:00, And for 08:00 am for 08:00, so php coding is just checking 03:00 verses 08:00, so event2 (with 03:00 pm) gets above and then event2 (with 08:00 AM). But Now I made changes in Jquery. Now it is inserting 15:00 Instead of 03:00 PM...Now It Is Working....Thanx for bearing pains for my problem

Answer (score 0):

What is stored in `event_start` field.Row id or other things.Check Your ascending pattern.

Comment: sorry respected member. Above Problem was related to jQuery datetimepicker addon. When I am adding date and time for event_start, it is inserting time as 03:00 pm for 15:00, And for 08:00 am for 08:00, so php coding is just checking 03:00 verses 08:00, so event2 (with 03:00 pm) gets above and then event2 (with 08:00 AM). But Now I made changes in Jquery. Now it is inserting 15:00 Instead of 03:00 PM...Now It Is Working....Thanx for bearing pains for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
$current_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s a");

$data=mysql_query("select * from  table where CAST(display_time AS DATETIME) >'".$current_date."' order by event_start asc");
```

Cast column according to your date format your passing

Comment: Thanx for your answer and Big sorry respected member as Above Problem was related to jQuery datetimepicker addon. When I am adding date and time for event_start, it is inserting time as 03:00 pm for 15:00, And for 08:00 am for 08:00, so php coding is just checking 03:00 verses 08:00, so event2 (with 03:00 pm) gets above and then event2 (with 08:00 AM). But Now I made changes in Jquery. Now it is inserting 15:00 Instead of 03:00 PM...Now It Is Working....Thanx for bearing pains for my problem